# Need to recursively remove license preamble

Tags: bash, sed

I want to recursively remove the

```
#region License
blah blah blah
blah blah blah
#endregion
```

text at the beginning of my .cs files.  How can I do this with a bash command?
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 sed  '/#region License/,/#endregion/d' ploum.cs
```

should do the trick.

To find all .cs files in the current subdirectories and run this on them:

```
find ./ -name "*.cs" -execdir sed '/#region License/,/#endregion/d' '{}' \;
```

Comment: +1, but you don't need the backslash.  (But could there be nested `#region` ... `#endregion` pairs within the License region?)

Comment: Thanks, huitseeker. By recursive, I mean from all files of the form *.cs

Comment: OK, to get the recursion I can call  find . -name *.cs | xargs sed -i '/#region\ License/,/#endregion/d'